# Broadcast Server

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, networking, tcp

I am writing a TCP Server that accepts connections from multiple clients, this server gathers data from the system that it's running on and transmits it to every connected client.

What design patterns would be best for this situation?

Example
Put all connections in an array, then loop through the array and send the data to each client one by one. Advantage: very easy to implement. Disadvantage: not very efficient when handling large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use some existing software to do this ... For example use https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=d5bedadd-e46f-4c97-af89-22d65ffee070 .

In case you want to write on your own you will need a list(linked list) to manage the connections.

Here is an example of a server http://examples.oreilly.com/jenut/Server.java

If you want to handle large amounts of data, one of the techniques is to have a queue associated with each of the subscribers at the server end. A multi-threaded program can send the data to the clients from those queues.

Answer (score 0):

A number of patterns have been developed for distributed processing and servers, for instance in the ACE project: http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html. The design might be focused around the events which announce either that data has been received and may be read, or that buffers have been emptied and more data may now be written. At least in the days when a 32-bit address space was the rule, you could have many more open connections than you had threads, so you would typically have a small number of threads waiting for events which announced that they could safely read or write without stalling until the other side co-operated. This may come from events, or from calls such as select() or poll() terminating. Patterns are also associated with http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#-MQ-in-a-Hundred-Words.